# Why can't I remove embed without deleting the message?

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

I want to delete **embed** without deleting the message. In the documentation it is written that if **embed = None**, the embed will be deleted. I have: discord=1.7.3 and discord.py=1.7.3

[image]

But this did not work for me.

[image]

[image]

```
@commands.command()
async def lol(self, ctx):
    embed = discord.Embed(title='Title', description='description', color=discord.Colour.gold())
    embed.add_field(name='name', value=f'value', inline=False)
    msg = await ctx.channel.send(embed=embed)
    await asyncio.sleep(1)
    await msg.edit(content='content', embed=None)
```

Comment: Have you tried using the `suppress` keyword-argument instead?

Comment: I tried, but it didn't work.

Comment: for me, it works exactly as you've said with no problem

Comment: what I can recommend if it doesn't work is trying to maybe update discord.py

Comment: I have the latest version of discord.py. I have no idea why it doesn't work for me.

Comment: I found out what the problem was. I use the "discord_components" library to use the discord buttons. The problem only exists when "discord_components" is initialized.

Answer (score 1):

I found out what the problem was. I use the "discord_components" library to use the discord buttons. The problem only exists when "discord_components" is initialized.

```
import discord
import discord.ext
import asyncio
from discord.ext import commands, tasks
from discord_components import DiscordComponents, Button, ButtonStyle, InteractionType

client = commands.Bot(command_prefix='!')

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    DiscordComponents(client)
    print('----------Ready---------')

@client.command()
async def lol(ctx):
    embed = discord.Embed(title='Title', description='description', color=discord.Colour.gold())
    embed.add_field(name='name', value=f'value', inline=False)
    msg = await ctx.channel.send(embed=embed)
    await asyncio.sleep(5)
    await msg.edit(content='content', embed=None, suppress=True)

client.run('***********************************************************')
```

Comment: Make sure that when you're asking a question, you have an example of code that fully reproduces the problem. [mre]

Comment: I will be careful in the future. Thank you.